# Как выставить dp в динамически созданном CardView?

Tags: android

Я создаю динамически CardView,

```
    CardView cards = new CardView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(450, 150);
    cards.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Но когда я выставляю setLayoutParams (450 по ширине, 150 высота), он выставляется судя по всему в пикселях, и поэтому на разных экранах выглядит по разному. То есть на Nexus 7 все отлично, а на других творится кошмар. Как задать размеры CardView в dp программерским способом?

Answer (score 2):

[На англоязычном ресурсе такой вопрос уже был - Converting pixels to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
Resources resources = context.getResources();
DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
return px;}

public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
Resources resources = context.getResources();
DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
return dp;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static float dpFromPx(final Context context, final float px) {
return px / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}

 public static float pxFromDp(final Context context, final float dp) {
return dp * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
}
```

Такая запись будет корректней, постараюсь объяснить почему. Так как на enStackOverflow, приведен просто пример, я постараюсь его описать кому-нить пригодится.

DisplayMetrics тягает инфу из `"ro.sf.lcd_density"` c помощью `SystemProperties` те из системы самого устройства и в случае если этих данных нет он использует `DENSITY_DEFAUL`, что по сути: `DENSITY_DEFAULT = DENSITY_MEDIUM` а это и есть `DENSITY_MEDIUM = 160`, и когда мы используем запись типа `float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);` мы слепо говорим что density = 160, он переведет в px правильно если scalefactor сработает корректно, но можно получить большую погрешность, тем более scale будет иметь не правильное значение. Все потому, что мы лишаем SystemProperties выбора настоящих параметров device из системного файла buil.prop(могу ошибиться).
А вот запись `getDisplayMetrics().density;` не лишает такой возможности и мы получим реальные данные из "ro.sf.lcd_density" и используем их в дальнейшем.

Еще маленький нюанс, раньше getDisplayMetrics мог давать погрешность на некоторых Device от API4 - API8, поэтому многие решали проблему с помощью `<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>`, понятно почему. После пару часов тестирования я нашел интересный факт, что совсем недавно большая часть DENSITY, были обновлены на оф ресусре, и сейчас даже если есть погрешность она очень мала, думаю что теперь можно смело использовать на всех API.